# How to pass the value between vue components when one's loading depends on another

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue Component with form data, the datas come from a request, and I also have a component which wants to loading it's grid data by using one element value of the first component's form.

Is there any suggestion can guide me to solve it? Thanks very much.

I'm using the Elements UI, and the components is multi hierarchy, It's not esay to get the component  I want by `$refs` or `$parents`

Comment: Can you add the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using VueX for this, it's state management framework.
So you would when you receive the data form the request save it in a store.
And then add a condition to render the second component. The second component will automatically re-render when the data is changed.

If you need more detailed help you'll have to post some code.

```
<my-component v-if="getDataForStore"></my-component>
```

Comment: thanks, I got an idea from you using Mixins code that contains watching the Store state's change, and finnaly I make it